# Does this Activity - Service messaging pattern cause a memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-service, android-lifecycle

I have a Worker `Service`, and a bunch of Activities. Every `Activity` has a `Handler`. The Activites can start jobs by sending `Intents` to the `Service` with the `startService` method. These jobs get into a queue, and are processed sequentially.

To report back the results of the finished jobs, I supply the proper Activity's `Handler` wrapped in a Messenger object with the `Intent` that describes the job. The `Service` sends back some message for the calling `Activity` through this. This works just fine.

But the supplied `Handlers` seems to remain in memory, even after the corresponding `Activites` got destroyed, continuing to handle the completion messages.

- How can this be? Shouldn't the handlers be destroyed with the `Activity` they're part of?
- Does this cause a memory leak?

Comment: You need to provide some code. How you declare your Intent objects in Activities? How you passing them to your Service? How Service keeps references to different Handlers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Service has a reference to the Itnents which still have a reference to the Activities Handler then the Handler isn't going to become available for Garbage Collection.

Have you seen [this video from Google IO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE)? It's about building apps that use RESTful web services so isn't directly relevant but the approach of delegating the responsibility for responding to long running events will partially map to your problem.

If you don't want to change things around too much then you need a way in your Activities onClose or onDestroy to notify the Service (and through it the Intent) that the long running task it is in charge of isn't needed anymore. It removes it's reference to the Handler and so the GC can get rid of it.

That or centralise the management (as in the video) of running tasks and responding to their lifecycle in a ServiceHelper class. That class can publish events as things happen and the activities can listen for those events.

This has the benefit of your code being in one place so you don't have to change every activity when you want to change how you handle the service.